# chkdsk /r issue for my pendrive - Insufficient disk space to recover lost data after agreeing to recover lost chains

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, chkdsk, fat32

today when I used my pendrive on my laptop I got this error -> "The files or directory is corrupted and unreadable" for all the files in a specific folder (about 2.5 gb of data)

googled the problem and followed the instructions online to use chkdsk to recover my data.

chkdsk /r command on cmd to recover the lost data. It ran for a while and found some inconsistencies. Then it asked me if I wanted to convert lost chains to files. I typed in yes and it gave me an error saying there is insufficient disk space to recover lost data. Here is the output :

```
C:\Users\Abhinav>chkdsk /r f:
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Volume Serial Number is 7A75-F6C6
Windows is verifying files and folders...
File and folder verification is complete.
Convert lost chains to files (Y/N)? y
Insufficient disk space to recover lost data.
2070416 KB in 513300 recovered files.
Windows is verifying free space...
Free space verification is complete.

Windows found problems with the file system that could not be corrected.
    7,953,572 KB total disk space.
          480 KB in 82 hidden files.
        1,172 KB in 191 folders.
      428,832 KB in 20,925 files.
    5,492,908 KB are available.

        4,096 bytes in each allocation unit.
    1,988,393 total allocation units on disk.
    1,373,227 allocation units available on disk.
```

Now my pendrive has a new folder named FOUND.000 that has .CHK files
I used Recuva afterwards to recover my files but it could not recover the files.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have a severe data loss, try to follow these steps:

**WRITE PROTECT your drive,** if possible.  Since you've got a flash drive, this might be easy to throw a switch, if provided.  Any attempted recovery, or even allowing Windows to mount the drive will do some writing to the drive, which can cause more losses.  FAT32 has ONE file allocation table, (which has the only pointers the which sectors represent which files and folders), so when that gets corrupted, "fixing it" can make matters worse.

**Do a complete TRUE IMAGE Backup** of your drive's PARTITION to another medium.  Do NOT use ANY program that does not offer a complete **sector-by-sector** copy of that partition.  (Suggestions welcome for a free version of reliable backup.  Ghost in the DOS days worked pretty well, using it's options).  Now, set your corrupted flash drive on the shelf and don't touch it, since it is possible you might need it again, and might want to still use it later to either restore this data, or start fresh.

**Make double the amount of room available on a drive you will be able to safely restore to.**  The perfect candidate might be an unused internal drive, or an external rotating drive.  If already formatted, you'll have to reduce the size of one of the partitions, preferably the last one, if there are more than one.  I would strongly recommend you don't use any system drive, and you had better know what you are doing when you restore that partition, since it is easy to make a mistake or not understand the backup software, and you inadvertently overwrite whatever was on that drive.  Recent versions of Windows can safely reduce the partition size to make room, as well as a number of other free third party tools.

**Restore your partition** to that (conventional) hard drive, understanding that if you mess up, or the software you are using does, you can destroy whatever was on the drive.

**NOW you can use whatever recovery tools you'd like,** without fear you'll mess it up, since you can always re-restore that partition and try again.  This is very close to what any forensics investigator would do. (Except they would copy from the first sector to the last, and not just the partition.  My company made a forensics tool used for this purpose in some notable criminal cases.)  If Windows can't recover, then try [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite) by Steve Gibson.  It isn't cheap, but it will recover most anything that is recoverable.  (It can also scan and fix many hardware problems on your flash drive, or most any hard drive.)

**PREVENT most problems from happening again by:**

**1.  NEVER unplugging ANY USB drive, until and unless Windows has unmounted the drive and said it is safe.**  There should be an icon, bottom right where you can right click to do this. Or there are a number of other ways to ensure that the drive is not being used.

**2.  Changing the partition type from FAT32 to NTFS.**  This NTFS file system is designed to recover from most file system problems.  For instance, NTFS keeps three file allocation tables.  So if you pull the drive out while writing to one of these tables, (one of the main causes of corruption), the other two will be used instead.  NTFS is an amazing file system.  However, Apple Macs can have problems when sharing a USB drive with a Windows PC, depending on which versions of both OS's, regardless of using FAT32 or NTFS partitions.  (I recommend using a network/internet file sync product, instead.)