# Can switching two drives wipe out a third drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a computer with multiple drives in Windows 10. A friend wanted me to recover files from a dead computer so I turned off my computer, disconnected one of the non OS drives and connected the friend's drive (all drives are SATA). Booted the machine and noticed to my big surprise one of my drives (a 2TB drive) got wiped out. All the folders and files are gone! Free disk space is the same as the size of the drive. I have no idea how this happened. I didn't touch the drive. The friend's drive was visible and I was able to copy files from it. After connecting my drive back, the 2TB drive still showed no files.
My next step is to use a disk recovery tool like GetMyData and I really hope it can recover the files. I won't be saving anything on it until then.

Any ideas what might have happened? I didn't format anything.

Comment: You sure your not looking at your friends disk instead of your disk which you said you disconnected?

Comment: No. As I said, I was able to copy files from his drive. Plus his drive is 750GB and mine is 2TB and clearly marked Hitachi in File Explorer which is mine.

Comment: BAD next step.  Your next step is to find another 2TB drive and make a forensic image.  Many times, some data can be recovered, but many recovery techniques will ruin the ability to get other data.  (When saving a good copy of retrievable data, writing that good copy will overwrite some other recoverable data.)  This may be far less lossy if you have a bit-for-bit "forensic" image of the drive.  Only after you do that should you try using software to restore old partition info, drive info, etc.

Comment: @TOOGAM While your idea sounds good, I have never seen a recovery tool which writes back to the same disk I am recovering from. They write the recovered files to another drive. I think they know better.

Comment: Tony_Henrich - I agree with @TOOGAM that ANY mounting of that hard drive in Windows does start doing some writing to the drive.  I just wrote up some extensive details of why, and how to recover any drive.  Although his loss was a USB FAT32 drive, all the principles are the same. http://superuser.com/questions/1175209/chkdsk-r-issue-for-my-pendrive-insufficient-disk-space-to-recover-lost-data-a/